# CentOS zip command - adding password - what type of encryption (if any) is provided?

Tags: encryption, zip, centos5

With the included zip utility in CentOS5 (zip command): i.e. `/usr/bin/zip -P $ZIP_PASS ...`

I haven't been able to find any documentation on this.  I am trying to find out how secure the password is.  Is this encrypted? How is it protected if not with encryption?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found the answer I was looking for.... From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_%28file_format%29 and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack

> Encrypted file archives such as ZIP are prone to this attack.[citation
>   needed] For example, an attacker with an encrypted ZIP file needs only
>   (part of) one unencrypted file from the archive which forms the
>   "known-plaintext".[4][5] Then using some publicly available software
>   they can quickly calculate the key required to decrypt the entire
>   archive. To obtain this unencrypted file the attacker could search the
>   website for a suitable file, find it from another archive they can
>   open, or manually try to reconstruct a plaintext file armed with the
>   knowledge of the filename from the encrypted archive.

So... the zip is not completely secure - but with random file names (when implemented well) for the file(s) inside the zip, and immediate deletion of the unencrypted file (which is also non-web-accessible) - this appears to be a POSSIBLE solution...

More resources:
http://linux.101hacks.com/archive-compression/password-protection-for-zip-files/

However, the more I read, **AES 256bit encrypted zips by 7zip** (once installed on the server) is much, much more secure.  It is NOT susceptible to the known plaintext attack, either.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is encrypted. Per the manual:

```
-P password
          use password to encrypt zipfile entries (if any).  THIS IS INSECURE!  Many multi-user operating
          systems provide ways for any user to see the current command line of any other  user;  even  on
          stand-alone  systems  there  is  always  the  threat of over-the-shoulder peeking.  Storing the
          plaintext password as part of a command line in an automated script is  even  worse.   Whenever
          possible,  use  the non-echoing, interactive prompt to enter passwords.  (And where security is
          truly important, use strong encryption such as Pretty Good Privacy instead  of  the  relatively
          weak encryption provided by standard zipfile utilities.)
```

This is just found from running "man zip" on a centOS machine.

As the manual entry notes, for high security it is not good to use the password in the command to zip the file, as others could check the process list and see the password as zipping.

I don't know what kind of encryption this uses, but I looked around some and it doesn't appear to be great. There are some similiar questions on stackoverflow to this. Look into using a different zip library if encryption is truly important, use something that allows AES, such as GPG.

Comment: found this: http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_zip.htm with all the info... I don't understand what the difference between `-e` and `-P` is?

Comment: If you use zip -e, you will be prompted to enter a password over stdin. If you use zip -P, you must provide the password in the call, ie. zip -P 'YouWontGuessMyPassword'. Otherwise you will get an Invalid Command argument error. It will be better to use the -e option.